# Analyzing files in SVN's rev folder

Tags: svn, svn-repository

I was analyzing files in the folders **"rev"** and **"revprop"** from a SVN repository when I find something written like this:

```
K 10
svn:author
V 11
Primoutente
K 8
svn:date
V 27
2015-12-03T17:30:44.000000Z
K 7
svn:log
V 43
Text of my comment

END
```

My question is: What do **"K"** and **"V"**, and the numbers reported close to them, mean?

Answer (score 2):

That are meta information.
**K** - key
**V** - value.
Both **K** and **V** are followed by a space and a number indicating the length of data.
In your example:
Key has length **10** (svn:author)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, again, what are "key" and "value" referred to? Is "key" a pointer to a file and value its revision? I still don't understand...

Comment: We accept, that was a commit in SVN. It has a "svn:author" with a name "Primoutente"  commited. It was commited on "svn:date" with a value: "2015-12-03T17:30:44.000000Z". And the comment "svn:log" of this commit was "Text of my comment..."

Comment: Ok, that's clear. But still, what are K and V about? do they refer to author, date and comment of the commit?

Comment: If you can see, you have many "K" and "V". For every property in this commit (author, date, ...) you have one key and one value. All this meta-informations are included in one block (BEGIN ... END) for every change in SVN.

Comment: Thank you again. And are they related to the kind of file or to the kind of folder related to the commit?

Comment: It is related to every new commit or every change of a file or directory in repository.

Comment: I mean, K states "the argument", for example the author, and V states the value of that argument, for example "Primoutente"....but what are the numbers close to K and V about?

Comment: We have in your example three properties: 1. svn:author 2. svn:data 3 svn:log. That are the keys with. The number 10 says, that the length of key: svn:author has 10 letters. The number 11 says, that the length of  "Primoutente" has 11 letters etc...

Comment: ah, ok. Now I get it. Thank you. The first time I read your previous comment I intended "lenght" as "extension"....sorry to have lead you to answer me so many times. You have been very kind.

Comment: Do you know even how to "decode" the exadecimal registers of the delta files in the repository?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have never done this. Please ask a new question on Stackoverflow.